# Is it possible to stop the rest of a command from running with a True or False assignment?

Tags: python

When you type `Attack` it sets `EnemyFighting` to `True`, and when you finish attacking it sets it to `False`. I don't want players to skip typing `Attack`. Is it possible to stop the rest of the command from running if `EnemyFighting == False`?

```
elif Input == 'Attack':
    EnemyCurrentHealth = 1
    print('You walk up to [TestDummy] and start to attack!')
    EnemyFighting = True
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Do you want to Kick or Punch [TestDummy]?')
elif Input == 'Kick':
    if EnemyFighting == False:
        exit()
    Damage = randint(0, 5)
    CurrentAttack = Damage
    if Damage >= 1:
        print('You hit [TestDummy] for ' + (str(CurrentAttack )) + ' KickDamage!')
    if Damage <= 0:
        print('You missed your kick!')
    EnemyCurrentHealth -= CurrentAttack
    if EnemyCurrentHealth <= 0:
        CoinGain = randint(3, 5)
        print('You Killed [TestDummy] and got +' + (str(CoinGain) + ' Coins!'))
        EnemyFighting = False
    print('Attack Cooldown - 1 Second(s)')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Attack Cooldown - 0 Second(s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the `if` condition:

```py
elif Input == 'Kick':
    if EnemyFighting != False:
        Damage = randint(0, 5)
        CurrentAttack = Damage
        if Damage >= 1:
            print('You hit [TestDummy] for ' + (str(CurrentAttack )) + ' KickDamage!')
        if Damage <= 0:
            print('You missed your kick!')
        EnemyCurrentHealth -= CurrentAttack
        if EnemyCurrentHealth <= 0:
            CoinGain = randint(3, 5)
            print('You Killed [TestDummy] and got +' + (str(CoinGain) + ' Coins!'))
            EnemyFighting = False
        print('Attack Cooldown - 1 Second(s)')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Attack Cooldown - 0 Second(s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check both `Input` and `EnemyFighting` in the `elif` clause:

```
elif Input == 'Kick' and EnemyFighting:
    ...
```